# When does a guitar neck bend happen and how to prevent it?

Tags: guitar, maintenance

We all know guitar necks bend and it is the worst thing that can happen to a guitarist but I would like to know what all the reasons that can cause it are? Some that I have heard are: (please explain why and preventive steps that can be taken)

1. Changing of string gauges
2. Not playing guitar for a long time
3. using floyd rose
4. Change of season

Comment: Do you mean damage to the neck, like warping?

Comment: yes warping is what i want to know about.

Answer (score 2):

All of those can put adverse pressure on the truss rod of the guitar and cause bowing. the reason being that the temperature change with the seasons, in combination with the humidity, can cause the wood to expand and contract causing bowing.

1. when adjusting to a new string gauge go have your truss rod adjusted to the new tension.
2. my best recommendation is to store it in a temperature controlled room where it has a stable humidity when storing for a long time. also playing your guitar every once and a while never hurt (:
3. Floyd Rose seems to be a product that would place a strange type of pressure on the guitar
4. Change of season causes expansion, and contract of the guitar so keeping in properly air conditioned as much as possible is key. The other side of the seasons coin is humidity the guitar is going to have the possibility of warping with too  much moisture of drying out if there is not enough moisture.

I hope this helps you be kind to your instrument (: